# Is the Jedi Order a Cult in context of modern Western society?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

Force sensitive children are taken from their families at a young age.  They live together, are trained together, and eventually are given a mentor to teach them the ways of the order.

They are forbidden to have attachments with others, be in family or love interests.

They have secret teachings and their own library.

In context of modern Western society, would the Jedi Order be considered a cult?

Comment: no they are a state backed, full fledged religion, with tax exempt status. monasteries have been around for a while now and while rare, are still accepted as part of main stream Christianity, catholic priests cannot marry, and monks give up pretty much all attachments and family ties.

Comment: @Himarm: Mass religions, mainstream or not, can arguably be deemed "cults" too. Merely identifying that some mainstream religions look similar to the Jedi Order doesn't in itself prove anything.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a mainstream state recognized religion by definition can no longer be considered a cult, as a cult is by DVK's definition something that is socially deviant, and since the majority of people in the U.S accept Christianity  (while not all parts) (and majority is over 50% though in the us its around 70% whether they practice or not) it is in fact not devient.

Comment: the rest of the major world religions again, by majority of the population of the world, consider them acceptable, even if they feel they are incorrect, or made up. the fact that they are tolerated on a worldwide level excludes them from being a cult.

Comment: @Himarm: Not sure why the focus on the USA? There's a whole world out here mate.

Comment: Now i will concede that smaller mainstream religions can be labeled a cult, such as Scientology, or even the Mormon church. As while they don't do anything that is really counter society, they have alot less proponents in being accepted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the question was about the west, the US is the prime example of western culture, but even in Europe Christianity is still widely accepted above the 50% mark, if not 60-80's.

Comment: @Himarm I don't think you can use an answer's definition to support a point about the question. The OP didn't give details about what is considered a cult. "In context of modern Western society" isn't very specific either. As you observed, *some* people (in the modern Western world) consider Scientology or the Mormon church cults, and others do not.

Comment: @KSmarts my point was, that comparing the jedi to Christianity, it terms of acceptance, that calling Christianity as a whole a cult, would you to be an outsider to popular opinion, and a small minority, so from my view the jedi would be accepted, and therefor not viewed as a cult. however since i didn't have enough to go on other then to guess i left my thoughts in a comment. but again, like i said, the main religions are not cults, as they have  massive world wide acceptance. and the various definitions of cults exclude organizations that are overwhelmingly accepted.

Comment: @Himarm Given that the focus of the story is on Jedi, we might be given skewed information about the acceptace of the Jedi Order. After all, by the time A New Hope rolls around, not 30 years later, Han calls the Force a hokey religion, and one of Vader's *own officers* criticizes his "sad devotion to that ancient religion". Of course, Palpatine has worked to discredit them, but the point is that we can't be sure.

Comment: "Cults" are generally centered on a single, charismatic leader.

Comment: @JoeL. - that's a consequence of how most things happen (including starting a new religion/cult) and not a defining characteristic.

Answer (score 4):

Impossible to answer definitively due to looseness of definition, but seems to be not a cult for most part.

> In the sociological classifications of religious movements, a cult is a religious or social group with socially deviant or novel beliefs and practices.[1] However, whether any particular group's beliefs and practices are sufficiently deviant or novel is often unclear, thus making a precise definition problematic.[2][3] In the English speaking world, the word often carries derogatory connotations (Wikipedia)

Let's see how that stacks up to your list:

> Force sensitive children are taken from their families at a young age.

The same is true of many gifted children in modern societies. Most notably, elite athletes, but also kids going to boarding schools.

**If you take away "Western" part, scientifically gifted kids gets the same treatment in China - and remember that Jedi Way has a lot more in common with Eastern religion/philosophies than Western ones, so that's where you should be comparing.**

The concept of the state taking away someone's kids in general is also quite common in modern West, see CPS.

In addition, the broad idea that the state knows better than the parents is deeply embedded in modern progressive mindset, with most of them absolutely opposed to homeschooling. See CPS again.

> They live together, are trained together,

Elite athletes again. Or boarding schools. Or Shaolin monastery.

> and eventually are given a mentor to teach them the ways of the order.

This is basically a master/apprentice model that goes all the way from 100% of tradesman history in all human societies, to thesis advisors in modern grad schools (if you take away 1-1 relationship which is hard to achieve logistically in most human teaching environments).

> They are forbidden to have attachments with others, be in family or love interests.

As Himarm's comment noted, there's this thing known as Catholic clergy. Quite the norm in many Western societies. I think it was also the norm for some Eastern monks, though I have less knowledge there so may be wrong.

> They have secret teachings and their own library.

Most Jedi teachings aren't secret. Merely not well known. Except for really advanced stuff. The same is true of modern military academies, NSA training, or for that matter Catholic Church/Jesuits. Or martial arts monasteries again.

---

---

P.S. Also, the concept of taking the kids away from their parents to be raised by special guardians is something intimately familiar and largely accepted by anyone raised on Soviet SciFi - namely, "internat" system from Strugatsky Brothers' "Noon" series  *(which in Soviet SciFi held the same place as Foundation, Dune, Star Wars, Tolkien and Heinlein hold put together in Western one)*.